# Конфликт уровней изоляции транзакций Spring Data и БД

Tags: java, база-данных, jpa, spring-data

В спринг-дата при использовании аннотации @Transactional предусмотрена возможность изменения уровня изоляции транзакций: Read Uncommitted, Read Committed, Repeatable Read, Serializable. Но также уровни изоляции есть и на слое базы данных. Какой уровень будет применен в случае несоответствия между этими слоями? Например, на уровне базы стоит repetable read, а спринг дата использует менее строгий read commited.

Comment: `Например, на уровне базы стоит repetable read, а спринг дата использует менее жесткий read commited` а такое может быть вообще?

Comment: Надо смотреть исходный код аннотации `@Transactional` - скорее всего там стоит установка уровня изоляции транзакции перед выполнением. То есть ответ - будет принят уровень изоляции в Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, надо смотреть на базу, но я не могу припомнить какой-то специфичной базенки, которая запрещала бы менять уровни изоляции, например, ниже чем дефолтный. Дефолтный уровень изоляции в СУБД никак не может конфликтовать с уровнем, который вы устанавливаете для транзакции. Сорян, что думал над ответом три года.

Comment: Да за три года, для себя понял, что уровень задается в приложении. База же может поддерживать или не поддерживать определенный уровень изоляции, но то какой это будет уровень определяет спринг.